# Unable to Start Blazor App in Chrome When Chrome is Already Open

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, blazor-webassembly

I created a Blazor Web Assembly app with .NET 6.0 using the template provided. I did not make any changes. When I try to run it when another Chrome window is open, a tab will open the says about:blank in the title and nothing in the window. In about 30 seconds later, I get an error message in Visual Studio that says “One or more errors occurred. Failed to launch debug adapter. Additional information may be available in the output window. Unable to launch browser: Could not connect to debug target at http://localhost:54906: Could not find any debuggable target.” I have tried changing multiple settings and I have repaired my Visual Studio and it still doesn’t work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thCKZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmFy4.png)

When I change the browser to Edge it works, but no in Chrome.

Comment: Also came searching for a solution to this. Mine has occurred a couple of times in the past and sometimes a system reboot solves it but that can't be the only solution. Something else is at play here